# Using Gnome-Shell themes for Unity possible?

Tags: unity, themes, command-line

I'd like to install some themes made for Gnome-Shell, like to know if they will work on Unity as well?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the elements will work, I would recommend downloading "[My Unity](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/myunity-30-released-with-new-gui.html)" to allow you to easily change the parts of the themes that you want to change. It will also allow you to customise other Unity setting easily, additionally it will come with some themes already installed.

[image: Here it what the themes tab looks like]

Some of the indicator apps will have unusual icon when you change the theme(classic-menu is one I know about) but as I said above most will work.

Answer (score 1):

The Gnome Shell themes themselves will not work , but the GTK themes that come with them for your window themes will, 9 times out of 10 work inside Unity.

Like posted earlier using "my unity" will show you themes and icons installed that can be used in Unity.